# Do we need to activate a service or do something to use web services?

Tags: 2013, development, web-services

So here's my problem. I'm willing to use SharePoint web services to write in lists, or get items, or get documents and all that fun stuff with web services.

**The problem is** that I get some errors and unfortunately I don't get any responses on them and google doesn't have any too.

**So my question is:**

> Do I have to activate anything to use web services? Like Basic authentication, or give certain permissions, or activate any other services.

Right now, from my application, i can log in into sharePoint. But that's all, I can't do anything more despite log in.

So I wonder if I have to do any more stuff on SharePoint side.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you share some more details about what you are trying to do that is causing errors? Maybe even post your code so we can see if there is an issue there. You said that aside from logging in, you cannot do anything more....that is kind of vague to me and likely to anyone else reading your question.

Comment: I've posted another question here with the error i got. No one is responding. The login is from the web services itself. Whe nyou connect to the web services it asks your credentials. Put them in then Soap error. Check my other question i posted here.

Answer (score 1):

No, you should not have to activate any service or anything.

I saw one of your other questions from earlier, and it seems you were instructed to use `copy.asmx` and you yourself had found `lists.asmx`.

**However**, you have tagged this question with [2013](/questions/tagged/2013), and if that is the case, I would highly recommend *not* using `lists.asmx` etc. and instead use the **REST API**.

Here are some resources about the REST API:

[REST API Reference and Samples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569.aspx)

[Working with lists and list items with REST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292552.aspx)

[Get to know the SharePoint 2013 REST service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142380.aspx)

[Complete basic operations using SharePoint 2013 REST endpoints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164022.aspx)

And there are many more out there if you just google "SharePoint 2013 REST".

In addition, to make things a little easier, I found this great JavaScript library that wraps the REST calls and lets you code in JavaScript in a much more similar style to what you would use for C#/server side code/Powershell:

[Bravo Core](https://github.com/bravocg/core)

<sup>(In fact, sometimes to help with administration, I'll create a page on a site, link that script to the page, open the page in a browser, and then run commands from the browser dev tools console.  It's like having Powershell in the browser console, no need to be on the server.)</sup>

Comment: Ok never used Rest time to start learning haha. So same question, do i need to activate anything on sharepoint side? And also, if central administrators would start being crazy, could they deactivate rest services?

Comment: As far as I understand, you should not need to activate anything to start using the REST services.  Also, I don't know if Admins can shut it down... there might be a way, but that's something I've never heard of before.

Comment: Ok cool, i will search a way to use Rest with delphi. That should be fun haha. Thank you for the answer helps me a lot :)